# Importing all variables from a file into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to import all variables from a file into a list?

Simplifying, this is precisely what I'm trying to achieve:

- I have a `config.py` file containing some variables like this, which strictly contains variables only:

  ```py
  # File: config.py

  NOSCRIPT = True
  TRANSFER_PB = False
  TIMEOUT = 7
  ...
  ```
- Now I have to import all of these variables from `config.py` file into `process.py`, so that I can get something similar to this when I run `process.py`

  ```py
  # File: process.py

  from config import *
  # Stuff to convert all imports into a list
  x = [NOSCRIPT, TRANSFER_PB, TIMEOUT, ...]
  ```

I know using wildcards are not really a great practice but I am left with no other option now due to the huge number of variables inside `config.py` (approx. 500+). Also I cannot edit the config file anyway. I'm probably missing something obvious, however it would be great if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: make a class in config.py and make the variables all class variables

Comment: Define variables in a `dict` and import only the dictionary? Since config files usually have variable names and values, I think it's the most suitable.

Comment: @Péter Leéh thanks for your input but sadly I cannot make any changes to the config file anyway.

Comment: why can't you edit the config file

Comment: `from . import config; x = [getattr(config, a) for a in dir(config) if not a.startswith('__')]`

Comment: How do we know what order this list should be? Would a dictionary be better than a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`from config import *` performs the following steps:

1. It imports `config` (without binding it to that name),
2. It checks whether `config.__all__` exists,
3. If it exists, use those names to import objects,
4. Otherwise, import everything that doesn't start with an underscore.

So you can do the following:

```py
import config

if hasattr(config, '__all__'):
    x = [getattr(config, name) for name in config.__all__]
else:
    x = [getattr(config, name) for name in dir(config) if not name.startswith('_')]
```

This is only approximately equivalent though since if `config.py` defines [`__dir__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/) then this is used for the result of `dir(config)` while `from config import *` still imports every name that doesn't start with an underscore, irregardless of `__dir__`.

**Note:** The result of `dir(config`) is alphabetized, i.e. `dir(config) == sorted(dir(config))`. That means the elements of the list do not necessarily appear in the order that they were defined in the original `config.py` file. Since dictionaries preserve insertion order since Python 3.7 you can use `for name in config.__dict__` instead, if that's important (this also sidesteps the `__dir__` difference).

Answer (score 3):

You could easily read them as CSV where `=` would be the separator.
Here's a csv reader function that additionnaly deals with `#` comments, and provides a generator.

```
import csv


def csv_dict_reader(file, has_header=False, skip_comment_char=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Reads CSV file into memory


    :param file: (str) path to csv file to read
    :param has_header: (bool) skip first line
    :param skip_comment_char: (str) optional character which, if found on first row, will skip row
    :param delimiter: (char) CSV delimiter char
    :param fieldnames: (list) CSV field names for dictionnary creation
    :param kwargs:
    :return: csv object that can be iterated
    """
    with open(file) as fp:
        csv_data = csv.DictReader(fp, **kwargs)
        # Skip header
        if has_header:
            next(csv_data)

        fieldnames = kwargs.get('fieldnames')
        for row in csv_data:
            # Skip commented out entries
            if fieldnames is not None:
                if skip_comment_char is not None:
                    if not row[fieldnames[0]].startswith(skip_comment_char):
                        yield row
                else:
                    yield row
            else:
                # list(row)[0] is key from row, works with Python 3.7+
                if skip_comment_char is not None:
                    if not row[list(row)[0]].startswith(skip_comment_char):
                        yield row
                else:
                    yield row
```

You can than use that function to read your config.py file, which you can convert to a dict like:

```
conf = csv_dict_reader('config.py', skip_comment_char='#', delimiter='=', fieldnames=['name', 'value'])

my_dict = {}

for line in conf:
    my_dict [line['name']] = line['value']

print(my_dict)
```

You may have to add `.strip()` to the names and values in order to remove trailing / ending white spaces.

Bear in mind that reading a python config file this way isn't very elegant.
You might consider using a 'real' config file format, with ConfigParser or so.

[EDIT] Just read your commment that you cannot change the config file format. So at least this should work[/EDIT]

Answer (score 2):

```
import config
x = [getattr(config, variable) for variable in dir(config) if not variable.startswith('__')]
```

Comment: As long as only the variable names are required, this is a beautiful pythonic solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
import config

x = {
       name: value 
       for name, value in vars(config).items() 
       if not name.startswith('__') 
    }
print(x)
# {'NOSCRIPT': True, 'TRANSFER_PB': False, 'TIMEOUT': 7, ...}
```

This simply imports the module, and looks through *every attribute it has* via `vars()`. `name.startswith('__')` will catch properties like `__dict__` and several various hidden auto-generated function and variables, so we can filter them out and then we're left with only the variables you started with.

And then now that you have a regular `dict` you can manipulate it however you want - take the keys, take the values, etc.